# Почему код не работает с массивом?

Tags: javascript, массивы

```
var shirina = 1000;

kolvoNone[0]=document.getElementsByClassName("picture_2")[0];
kolvoNone[0].style.width=shirina;
```

если работать без массива, то ширина картинки записывается. Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: Без какого массива? kolvoNone? Вы его объявили?

Answer (score 3):

Просто вы забыли объявить массив – его просто не существует. И следующая ошибка – ширина измеряется в `style` не просто как число, а как число с указанием названия измерения этих единиц – к примеру, `"1000px"`.

Также можно всё это записать так:

```
kolvoNone[0].setAttribute("width", 1000);
```

вместо указания ширины через `style`. Здесь уже она идёт без единиц измерения.

Поэтому сначала объявляем массив, а потом записываем в него:

```
var shirina = "1000px";
var kolvoNone = [];

kolvoNone[0] = document.getElementsByClassName("picture_2")[0];
kolvoNone[0].style.width = shirina;
```